# Adding a new dictionary to my plist file

Tags: iphone, plist, nsdictionary

Root  ---- Array
  Item 0- Dictionary
    fullName  ---- String
    address   ---- String
  Item 1   ---- Dictionary
    fullName  ---- String
    address   ---- String

I have a plist that looks like the one about.  In a View I have a button that when clicked I'd like to add a new "Item 2" or 3 or 4 or 5 etc...  I just want to add a few more names and addresses.

I've spent 3 hours tonight searching for the perfect example but came up short. The Apple property lists samples were way too deep.  I've seen code that probably will come close.

Thanks So Much

`NSMutableDictionary *nameDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [nameDictionary setValue:@"John Doe" forKey:@"fullName"];
    [nameDictionary setValue:@"555 W 1st St" forKey:@"address"];`

```
NSMutableArray *plist = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:[self dataFilePath]];
[plist addObject:nameDictionary];
[plist writeToFile:[self dataFilePath] atomically:YES];
```

`- (NSString *)dataFilePath {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"children.plist"];
    return path;
}`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming that the plist is stored on disk as a file, you can reopen it and load new contents by calling the `arrayWithContentsOfFile` method.

```
// Create the new dictionary that will be inserted into the plist.
NSMutableDictionary *nameDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[nameDictionary setValue:@"John Doe" forKey:@"fullName"];
[nameDictionary setValue:@"555 W 1st St" forKey:@"address"];

// Open the plist from the filesystem.
NSMutableArray *plist = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:@"/path/to/file.plist"];
if (plist == nil) plist = [NSMutableArray array];
[plist addObject:nameDictionary];
[plist writeToFile:@"/path/to/file.plist" atomically:YES];
```

The `-(void)addObject:(id)object` always inserts at the end of the array. If you need to insert at a specific index use `-(void)insertObject:(id)object atIndex:(NSUInteger)index` method.

```
[plist insertObject:nameDictionary atIndex:2];
```

Comment: I'm confused.  How exactly does that add a "Item #" and it's corresponding string key/values?  Remember I'm totally new to the iOS development environment.

Comment: Thanks.  That is much more simpler to understand.  I was wondering how it handles new lines.  Thank You So Much.  I will go forth and try this now.

Comment: Timed out fetching data. Variable display may be inaccurate.
Timed out fetching data. Variable display may be inaccurate.
Timed out fetching data. Variable display may be inaccurate.

Comment: This code seems to work but it's not putting the values into the .plist file in my project.  I've got the children.plist file inside my resources "folder" of my project (the same place I'm storing png and xib files).  My code is...  SEE ABOVE in my original post

Comment: The plist file needs to exists in order for the `arrayWithContentsOfFile:` to work. If it does not then the return value will be `nil`. I edited the answer to test for `nil`.

Comment: I'm changing all the @"/path/to/file.plist" to @"filename.plist" which is a plist file in the root of my resources folder.  The code does not error but the new values are being inserted into the plist.  Thoughts??  I can read the plist to build my tableview so that's a bit bazaar.

Comment: I just learned that when you are editing a plist vs writting to it you have to store it in the hidden "Documents" directory.